# State not updating when using useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am learning how to useContext.  I have a button click that is updating my state but when I try to useContext on another component it doesnt seem to be updating that state.  I can see the state updating on my card component. When I consolelog the test in my Context it doesn't show any state passed to it.  I am passing the state from the card component into the cardContext so I can use elsewhere

Card Component setting state

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

import './Card.css';

function Card() {
    const API_KEY = '';
    const BASE_URL = ``;

    const [coins, setCoins] = useState([]);
   
    const [tests, setTests] = useState('');

    // console.log(coinsSelected);
    console.log(tests);

    const getPrice = async () => {
        const updatedPrice = await axios.get(BASE_URL);
        setCoins(updatedPrice.data);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getPrice();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="card-container">
            {coins.map((coin) => (
                <div className="card" key={coin.id}>
                    <div className="flip-card">
                        <div className="flip-card-inner">
                            <div className="flip-card-front">
                                {coin.logo_url === '' ? (
                                    <h1>No Image</h1>
                                ) : (
                                    <img src={coin.logo_url} alt="coin"></img>
                                )}
                                <div className="flip-card-price">
                                    <h3>{coin.name}</h3>

                                    <p>{coin.price}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div className="flip-card-back">
                                <h3>ATH -{coin.high}</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card__button">
                        <Button
                            variant="primary"
                            
                            onClick={(e) => setTests(e.currentTarget.value)}
                            value={coin.id}
                        >
                            Buy
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
export default Card;
```

CardContext

```
export const CardContext = createContext();

export const CardProvider = (props) => {
    const [coinsSelected, setCoinsSelected] = useState([]);
    const [tests, setTests] = useState('');

    return (
        <CardContext.Provider value={[tests, setTests]}>
            {props.children}
        </CardContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Trying to use Context here

```
import { CardContext } from '../../Context/CardContext';

function Swap() {
    const [tests, setTests] = useContext(CardContext);

    console.log('foo', tests);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{tests}</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Swap;
```

Sample Data

````
    "id": "BNB",
    "currency": "BNB",
    "symbol": "BNB",
    "name": "Binance Coin",
    "logo_url": "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nomics-api/static/images/currencies/bnb.svg",
    "status": "active",
    "platform_currency": "BNB",
    "price": "362.89854083",
    "price_date": "2022-02-25T00:00:00Z",
    "price_timestamp": "2022-02-25T05:49:00Z",
    "circulating_supply": "168137036",
    "max_supply": "168137036",
    "market_cap": "61016684987"
}```
````

Comment: Where is the `CardContext` used? Where are you reading its state and calling `setTests` to update it?

Comment: I've updated my question.  I am calling setTests  in my card component onClick

Comment: The `Card` component is calling its own `setTests` state updater though, not the one in the context.

Comment: That is what I was figuring.... I just can't wrap my head around how I would set the state in the context then.  I figured that setting the state in the card would also set it in the context

Comment: You appear to have duplicated the context state in the `Card` component. Just swap the `Card` component's state for what's returned by the context and use that state and state updater instead. Do you need help with this part?

Comment: Yes please,  I was trying to figure it out but I just can't seem to get it

Comment: Ok, can you add sample `updatedPrice.data` response data so I can mock the `coins` state?

Comment: Updated post with sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the `Card` component to access the `CardContext` value it must be rendered in the subtree created by `CardProvider`. It can then destructure and access the `tests` and `setTests` context values.

Example:

```
const CardContext = createContext(["", () => {}]);

const CardProvider = (props) => {
  const [coinsSelected, setCoinsSelected] = useState([]);
  const [tests, setTests] = useState("");

  return (
    <CardContext.Provider value={[tests, setTests]}>
      {props.children}
    </CardContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

...

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CardProvider>
        <Card />
      </CardProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

...

```
function Card() {
  const API_KEY = "";
  const BASE_URL = ``;

  const [coins, setCoins] = useState([]);

  const [tests, setTests] = useContext(CardContext); // <-- access context value

  console.log(tests);

  const getPrice = async () => {
    const updatedPrice = await axios.get(BASE_URL);
    setCoins(updatedPrice.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getPrice();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="card-container">
      {coins.map((coin) => (
        <div className="card" key={coin.id}>
          <div className="flip-card">
            <div className="flip-card-inner">
              <div className="flip-card-front">
                {coin.logo_url === "" ? (
                  <h1>No Image</h1>
                ) : (
                  <img src={coin.logo_url} alt="coin" height={100} />
                )}
                <div className="flip-card-price">
                  <h3>{coin.name}</h3>

                  <p>{coin.price}</p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="flip-card-back">
                <h3>ATH -{coin.high}</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="card__button">
            <Button
              variant="primary"
              onClick={(e) => setTests(coin.id)}
            >
              Buy
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit state-not-updating-when-using-usecontext]

Comment: Awesome it worked!   Can you please explain what is going on this line for me const CardContext = createContext(["", () => {}]);

Comment: @arod1207 Oh, that is only the [default value](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext). Useful if you attempt to access the context value outside any provider. It can also help with type inferences, i.e. with intellisense in IDEs that support and use it. It's not required by any means.

Comment: Thank you for the information and the help